# deploy rails choices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

After I finished reading Agile Web Development with Rails, I Have developed my own website.

Now I am trying to deploy my project on linux system I rent, but I know nothing about how to deploy rails.Which server should I user? How to connect to mysql database?

As a java developer, I know I can use tomcat as my server which can convert http request to my own object and use jdbc to connect to my mysql database.

Now I want to know what is the main stream environment rails deployed?

I have heard of Lighttpd and FCGI. Can I use them in the product environment?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your linux system a full VPS (you have complete control?)  If not, check your hosting company to see what options are available to you.  If so, check to see if they have guides for setting up Rails.  A lot (Slicehost, Linode, etc.) do.

Failing that... I would recommend either Apache (or Nginx) with Passenger.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/

It's pretty straight forward.

As for actually deploying, look into Capistrano (or Vlad).  These are a little bit more complicated, but they make life so much easier in the long run.

Comment: yes I have complete control.I know nothing about Passenger I will learn it today Thanks :)